# How to deal with datepicker in Appium Android

Tags: java, android, selenium, datepicker, appium

My android application is using datepicker but i am not able to select date through datepicker. I used following code in application for datepicker but it does not work.

```
List<WebElement> pick = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));           

pick.get(0).sendKeys("21");
pick.get(1).sendKeys("Mar");
pick.get(2).sendKeys("1989");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*it does not work*"?

Comment: you can use swipe method to select and scroll dates. Sendkeys will not work there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Xpath to perform Datepicker action & it is working properly.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']")).sendKeys("Jan");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']")).sendKeys("24");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='2']")).sendKeys("1987");

Comment: I know this post is too old, but I have used the same code but this is not working

Comment: @DrPatience No! What about you?

Comment: @AnswerDroid unfortunately not! still working it out

Comment: Works for me! Appium 1.9.1 thanks bud @Rohit Doraya

Answer (score 2):

Swipe method will help you to scroll calendar dates  , Make sure that you have added Java-client JARs to your project then only swipe method will support.

Example :

```
First click on your calendar icon and then use following code :

Thread.sleep(5000);
 for(int y=0;y<3;y++)
    {

        driver.swipe(350,511,350,577,0);  


    }
```

Swipe Syntax :

> driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration);

**Note : Above in code I have used sample co-ordinates so you change it according to your need. You can get exact co-ordinates from bound values of that date picker.**

I have used loop in above code as I want to swipe 3 times , so it is something like if current date is **1st may** then it will swipe till **4th may.**

you can modify loop as per your need.

Comment: I think if we have devices whose screen size differs from each other, using co-ordinates is bit risky.

Comment: Yes, this concept works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For all the user who are still finding the way to select date can use the below code. I am using this code and working perfectly for me. It will work for calendar attached.

```
do {      
    WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@instance='0']"));    
    WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@instance='22']"));       
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions)driver);    
    System.out.println("Dragging item");    
    action.longPress(source).moveTo(destination).release().perform();   
    boolean bul = driver.findElementsByXPath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='24 January 2018']").isEmpty();

  } while(bul!=false);   

driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("24 January 2018").click();
```

**NOTE:** I used drag and drop touch action to scroll and this will scroll uptill given date is not found. I just selected same years previous month date. You can use same touch action to select desired year.

Comment: Hi there, please consider editing the answer and formatting the code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing, but for a "calendar" mode DatePicker instead of the "spinner" mode. This is my solution, which has been working fine for me.

```
from datetime import datetime

datePickerYearTextViewXpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='android:id/date_picker_header_year']"

# initialize your appium driver here
driver = getAppiumDriver()

# define some screen dimensions
screenSize = driver.get_window_size()
halfScreenWidth = screenSize['width'] // 2
halfScreenHeight = screenSize['height'] // 2


def getDatePickerCurrentDate(driver):
    yearTextView = driver.find_element_by_xpath(datePickerYearTextViewXpath)
    yearString = yearTextView.text
    dateTextView = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='android:id/date_picker_header_date']")
    dateString = dateTextView.text
    fullDateString = '{}, {}'.format(dateString, yearString)
    currentDate = datetime.strptime(fullDateString, '%a, %b %d, %Y').date()

    return currentDate


def setDatePickerDate(driver, targetDate):
    # driver is an appium driver
    # targetDate must be a datetime.date, not a datetime

    currentDate = getDatePickerCurrentDate(driver)

    if targetDate.year != currentDate.year:
        yearTextView = driver.find_element_by_xpath(datePickerYearTextViewXpath)
        yearTextView.click()

        # you may need to adjust the following numbers
        # depending on your screen size
        swipeAmountPerYear = 49
        yearsPerScreen = 8
        swipeDuration = 400

        yearOffset = targetDate.year - currentDate.year
        # if target year is older, swipe up (negative)
        swipeDirection = -1 if yearOffset < 0 else 1
        swipeVector = yearsPerScreen * swipeAmountPerYear * swipeDirection
        while True:
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='android:id/text1']".format(targetDate.year))
            found = False
            for element in elements:
                if element.text == str(targetDate.year):
                    element.click()
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                break
            else:
                driver.swipe(halfScreenWidth, halfScreenHeight, halfScreenWidth, halfScreenHeight - swipeVector, swipeDuration)

    currentDate = getDatePickerCurrentDate(driver)

    if targetDate.month != currentDate.month:
        monthOffset = targetDate.month - currentDate.month
        prevOrNext = 'prev' if monthOffset < 0 else 'next'
        prevOrNextButtonXpath = "//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='android:id/{}']".format(prevOrNext)
        for i in range(abs(monthOffset)):
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(prevOrNextButtonXpath).click()

    targetDateContentDescription = targetDate.strftime('%d %B %Y')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.view.View[@resource-id='android:id/month_view']/android.view.View[@content-desc='{}']".format(targetDateContentDescription)).click()

    currentDate = getDatePickerCurrentDate(driver)
    if currentDate != targetDate:
        raise ValueError('Unable to set date picker({}) to target date({})!'.format(currentDate, targetDate))
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if [this](https://pravinmagdum.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/select-date-with-android-datepicker-appium/) helps

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("com.eos.eos_du_su:id/ed_manufdate")).Click();
((AndroidElement)(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']//android.widget.Button[@index=0]")))).Tap(1, 2);

((AndroidElement)(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']//android.widget.Button[@index=0]")))).Tap(1, 2);

((AndroidElement)(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='2']//android.widget.Button[@index=0]")))).Tap(1, 2);

driver.FindElement(By.Id("android:id/button1")).Click();
```